# unionAll on round 300 pyspark dfs using reduce, final dataframe takes a lot time just to count rows. What is going wrong and how can I resolve it?

Tags: python, performance, join, pyspark

I have 300 pyspark dataframe in the list. I want to unionAll the dataframe to have single consolidated pyspark dataframe. I have used reduce function to stack one dataframe over another. But after I got the final stacked dataframe, it takes 10 mins just to show the number of rows. This is probably because of partitions. Is there any convenient solution to tackle this issue ?

Thanks.

```
Lst = [ df1, df2, ... df300]

Final_df = reduce(Dataframe.unionAll, Lst)
```

#Final_df has around 20000 rows but it slowed down the operations that we perform on the same dataframe. E.G. it takes 10 min just to show row count.

Comment: How do you load this list of dfs? is it a result of other set of aggregations/processing? or you load it from a datasource like files? Asking because if there are aggregations and processing without actions to create this list then the processing is done only when you call the action (count function). Also did you try to count each df separability and monitor the time?

Comment: Hello. I am performing a groupby on a single dataframe and then taking out the individual dataframes in a loop. So if I am having 384 such dataframes it is creating 384 partitions when I stack them over one another. I used coalesce to reduce the number of partions. Performance improves a bit but still not good enough. Is there any better idea to store these dataframes or should I use pandas dataframes instead ?

Comment: Splitting the original dataframe into multiple small ones and then try to stack them again is not a beneficiary usage of Spark, if you can explain the full logic you are trying to do and more code then I can check an efficient way to map into Spark operations without the need to split the df